# Style input placeholders

Tags: html, css, forms, placeholder

There are 3 forms on my website and I want to style their placeholders. I want all other inputs on website keep their own styling.
It seems to me that I managed to style inputs of one form, but how to group styles for all 3 forms

```css
.one-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #d6d6d6; }
.one-form input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */ color: #d6d6d6; }
.one-form input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */ color: #d6d6d6; }
.one-form input:-ms-input-placeholder {   color: #d6d6d6; }
```

```html
<form class="one-form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="log" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" name="1-submit" id="1-submit" value="Start" />  
</form>

<form class="three-form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="smthing" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" name="someth" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" name="1-submit" id="1-submit" value="Start" />  
</form>

<form class="two-form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="smth" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" name="some" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" name="1-submit" id="1-submit" value="Start" />  
</form>
```

I am asking because I read somwhere that if you group css it will be ignored totally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the desired style to a common class between all forms. (E.g `.one-form`)

```css
.one-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #d6d6d6; }
.one-form input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */ color: #d6d6d6; }
.one-form input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */ color: #d6d6d6; }
.one-form input:-ms-input-placeholder {   color: #d6d6d6; }
```

```html
<form class="one-form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="log" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" name="1-submit" id="1-submit" value="Start" />  
</form>

<form class="three-form one-form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="smthing" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" name="someth" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" name="1-submit" id="1-submit" value="Start" />  
</form>

<form class="two-form one-form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="smth" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" name="some" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" name="1-submit" id="1-submit" value="Start" />  
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add one common class in all three form and style it.

```css
.custom-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #d6d6d6; }
.custom-form input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */ color: #d6d6d6; }
.custom-form input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */ color: #d6d6d6; }
.custom-form input:-ms-input-placeholder {   color: #d6d6d6; }
```

```html
<form class="one-form custom-form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="log" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" name="1-submit" id="1-submit" value="Start" />  
</form>

<form class="three-form custom-form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="smthing" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" name="someth" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" name="1-submit" id="1-submit" value="Start" />  
</form>

<form class="two-form custom-form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="smth" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" name="some" placeholder="Password" />
  <input type="submit" name="1-submit" id="1-submit" value="Start" />  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple selectors into your rule:

```
.one-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.two-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.three-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
   color: #d6d6d6;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if i got this correctly but you can do this

```
.one-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.two-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.three-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder{ color: #d6d6d6; }

.one-form input:-moz-placeholder,
.two-form input:-moz-placeholder,
.three-form input:-moz-placeholder{ /* Firefox 18- */ color: #d6d6d6; }

.one-form input::-moz-placeholder,
.two-form input::-moz-placeholder,
.three-form input::-moz-placeholder{  /* Firefox 19+ */ color: #d6d6d6; }

.one-form input:-ms-input-placeholder,
.two-form input:-ms-input-placeholder,
.three-form input:-ms-input-placeholder{   color: #d6d6d6; }
```

JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ts57n0np/

Comment: @kilogram This answer has 3 times the amount of code it needs. You're much better off putting a common class on the elements so you only need to style them once: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40765857/4573410

Comment: Oh yes I also think this way now. I am putting a common class